# Insert data from SQL file in Django DB

Tags: python, django, database

I'm working on a Django Project, and I have all my datas in .sql files.
I want to insert all of them in my Database.
Can I use the python shell to do it ? Or should I use another method ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have file or can convert your data into csv or xml then you can make a script which iterate through your data file and then store each data into variable and as per your Django model fields and then you can bulk_create